# React hyperlink in a NavLink

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need your suggestions and ideas please. I'm using a long sentence in a react `<NavLink>` to point to a page. I'm supposed to make just the **"Click here"** show the hand and make it clickable to the component. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <NavLink to="/page">
      This is long sentence but "click here" to get to the page
    </Navlink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        This is long sentence but <NavLink to="/page">click here</NavLink> to get to the page
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap "click here" with the NavLink:

```
<ul>
    <li>
This is long sentence but
    <NavLink to="/page">
     "click here" 
    </Navlink>
to get to the page
    </li>
    </ul>
```

NavLinks are essentially just anchor tags and function the same way

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md